# reset form validation from in an other form with button

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

i am using from validation.io but I have a problem.
I dont reset field validations form1, it works correcty in form2.

I tryed trigger but didnt work.

how can I do? do you have an idea my friends?

```
<form id="form1">
    <input type="reset" click="resetForm2()">
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input id="text1" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text2" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text3" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text4" type="text" value="value">
    .
    .
    .
    <input id="text16" type="text" value="value">
    <input type="reset" click="resetForm2()">
</form>
```

formvalidation reset metod

```
function reserForm2()
{
    $('#form2').data('formValidation').resetForm($('#form2'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `form="form2"` attribute to rest button. Refer to [this](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/) for details.

```js
function reserForm2()
{
    $('#form2').data('formValidation').resetForm($('#form2'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
    <input type="reset" click="resetForm2()" form="form2">
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <input id="text1" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text2" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text3" type="text" value="value">
    <input id="text4" type="text" value="value">

    <input id="text16" type="text" value="value">
    <input type="reset" click="resetForm2()">
</form>
```